# login in gmail using seleniun in heroku

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, automation

I am writing a python program to delete a number of email from same user and for it i am using selenium as an automation program and to host that program in heroku
The problem is when i login in gmail in my pc it is working just fine where as when i try it from selenium it gives me an error saying that it can't find email input field

**note :** *to make selenium work on heroku i have use this [method](https://www.andressevilla.com/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku/)*

here is my code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')
driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys('gpt.sahaj28@gmail.com') # here is when the error occur in heroku
driver.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
```

**at second last line error occur in heroku where as it works just fine in pc**

i cant seem to figure out problem

Comment: Gmail is bloking access for automated scripts, see: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

So I highly don't suggest using selenium to delete a user's email, as it may be violated Gmail's Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. What I suggest more is using [Gmail's API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) to manage user's emails. Hope that helps.

Comment: Even if i am deleting emails from my own gmail?